Dynamically Switching Vuforia Model Target Detection via Script
I want to know if there is a way to use a script to control which model target to detect when using Vuforia. For example, I have a database and it is currently detecting Model A. Can I use a script to make it detect Model B instead?
I have tried using VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.ObserverFactory.CreateModelTarget but it did not successfully create the target.
Thank you for your help.

The easiest is probably just to deactivate the GameObject of the Model Target.
So, in a method, add
modelTarget_A.enabled = false;
modelTarget_B.enabled = true;
CreateModelTarget() shouldn't be used as this just creates the Model Target Behaviour at runtime. If you have the Model Target GameObjects in the scene, then they are created at initialization and active by default.
Hope it helps,

It worked, I think I was making this question more complicated than it needed to be. Thank you for your answer.

@Uparupa if an answer solves your question please consider to mark it as the accepted answer (✔ button) in order to indicate that a) there already is an answer and b) help others with similar question to find the answer more easily

Ok, I got it, thanks for reminding.
